# Get list of elements with class name in javascript with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get a list of elements with a certain class name in javascript with selenium?

I am searching for any elements with the class `message_body`. I want a array containing all of the elements that have that class.

`driver.findElements(By.className("message_body"))` doesn't work, it seems to return something else.

How can I get this list?

Comment: What does it seem to return? And what kind of array are you looking for? (Can you show the assignment you make with `driver.findElements(By.className("message_body"))`?

Comment: @Tyler I am not sure.  Another SO answer said it returns a `promise`, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example to get the text from a list of elements:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("message_body")).then(function(elements){
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.getText().then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm using an older version of Selenium, v2.47.1, but something I used when `driver.findElements(By.className("someClass"))` wasn't sufficient was `driver.findElements(By.xpath("/path/to/[@class='someClass']"))` . This will return a `List<WebElement>`. If I remember correctly, `By.xpath` is a little slower than some of the other options on some browsers, but not by a whole lot....

Comment: This is javascript, so I don't think a `List<WebElement>` will be returned, but this might work.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. It gives `driver.findElements is not a function`.

Comment: Oh! I misread that as java -- this is a java function. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the elements collection:

```
public async getInstalledApps(): Promise<any[]> {
   const appsList: WebComponent = this.browser.find(By.css(`div .icons__title`));
   return await appsList.getElements();
}
```

Then, using the function above you can do anything, for example get the text property and save them. For example if it's a group of Apps button and you want to get a names array of them:

```
public async getInstalledAppsList(): Promise<string[]> {
const appsList: string[] = [];
let app: string = '';

(await this.getInstalledApps()).forEach(async element => {
  await Promise.resolve(element).then(async (text: any) => {
    app = await (await text.getText());
    appsList.push(app);
  });
});

return appsList;
}
```